# I need to reload a table view menu when user login or logout with swreveal controller on swift?

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a "Login" button on my table view menu. When user touches, it shows the login view i need. When user logs in successfully, reload the table view to hide "login" button and show "Account" Button and viceversa on swift

Comment: What is "secessfull relead"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you do with button. My team and I usually use table cell like a menu item. Like this example

[image]

[image]

- I defined a menu item array

  `var menuItems = ["Sign in", "My abc", "My def"]`
- And code for sign in function, remove "Sign in" and add "My Account". In my simple example, I use didSelectRowAtIndex and check "Sign In" menu

  ```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  // sign in item
     if indexPath.row == 0 && menuItems[0] == "Sign in" {

         let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Signing in", message: "Press OK to sign in", preferredStyle: .Alert)

         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

             self.menuItems.removeAtIndex(0)
             self.menuItems.insert("My Account", atIndex: 0)

             tableView.reloadData()
         }))

         presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
  ```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The way i solved it was to reload table view in `viewWillAppear()` method

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //Since i didnt use UITableViewController...
    @IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView! 

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        menuTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Some other methods handled sign out, login and table view list items